# Mysql: update records from source table into destination table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 identical tables. The 'Number' and 'Productcode' fiels form the unique key. This unique key combination is for both table's identical.

I want to insert records from table 2 into table 1. It could be that a record unique key already exists. In that case the record needs to be updated for all fields. But... The record only needs to be updated if the date field from table 2 record is more recent then the date field from table 1.

I tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO Table_dest (Number, Productcode, TransactionDate,
                        TransactionTime, Price)
SELECT
  Number, Productcode, TransactionDate, TransactionTime, Price
FROM
  Table_source
WHERE
  Table_source.TransactionDate >= Table_dest.TransactionDate
  AND Table_source.TransactionTime > Table_dest.TransactionTime;
```

But it gives me error's on the WHERE clause.
It also gives error's on duplicates, but i don't know how to adress that.
Anyone any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow this format while joining two tables:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (a1, a2, a3)

SELECT b1, b2, b3
FROM tableB b
JOIN tableA a ON a.a1 = b.b1
WHERE (CONDITION)
```

See if it working for you.

Comment: Try running only select query and check what it results. Number of columns in source and destination table must match.

Comment: Thanks! I did the following: INSERT INTO Table_dest (Number, Productcode, TransactionDate, TransactionTime, Price) SELECT Number, Productcode, TransactionDate, TransactionTime, Price FROM Table_source s LEFT JOIN Table_dest d ON s.Number = d.Number AND s.Productcode = d.Productcode WHERE s.TransactionDate >= s.TransactionDate AND s.TransactionTime > d.TransactionTime; But now it give's me an error message: "Column 'Number' in field list is ambiguous".

Comment: This error results due to fields are named the same way. Like both tables have fields with same name. MySQL engine could not decide which table to follow. Try something like this: `SELECT s.Number, s.Productcode`

Comment: Thanks Harpeet. That fixed it. Only thing left now is that is only inserts records that it finds in both tables. I will try to figure out how to solve that to.